# Send string from webapp to PowerShell

Tags: c#, string, powershell

I try to send from my webapp  to Powershell command as follow command
.\send-message.ps1 -filename "CurrentUnloadingPlaning20240320142613833.json" -queuePath "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:GTH-RCWEB.NOVELIS.BIZ\private$\srs_pdi"

when I building string C# give back follow string
".\send-message.ps1 -filename "CurrentUnloadingPlaning20240320152128068.json" -queuePath "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:server\private$\srs_pdi""

Give error file don't exist
\msmq-powershell-test\send-message.ps1 : The file '\CurrentUnloadingPlaning20240320152128068.json' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

```
string nameFile = "CurrentUnloadingPlaning" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".json";
const string quote = @"""";
string Filename = quote + nameFile + quote;
string commandscript1 = @".\send-message.ps1 -filename " + Filename;
string commandscript2  = @" -queuePath " + @"""FormatName:DIRECT=OS 
server\private$\srs_pdi""";
string command1 =  commandscript1 + commandscript2;
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the full path to the file?

Comment: string destinationDirectory = @"W:\L2\RC\ESRS\ToL2\";